# How to locate intersections of a specific city?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am looking to find the longitude/latitude of all street intersections of Chicago. I happened to stumble upon overpass turbo, but I'm unfamiliar with how to code for it. I found this code below locates all intersections for an area in New York city, but I need to find the intersections of Chicago. How would I do this?

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/QD

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing "New York" specific in your query, except for the initial location when you start up the overpass turbo link. Just move the map to where you want to find intersections, and hit "Run". That's really all, no need for any sort of coding here.